# PDOStatement::execute with parameters

Tags: php, pdo

This page is really not clear for the function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

I'm not exactly sure why I would bindParam as oppose to just passing in an array. With bindParam, I'll have to specify the type.

So my question would be, if I just do `$stmt->execute(array("somevalue", b'somebinarydata', 10203, 201.3));`, would the types be automatically recognized? Is there anything I have be aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question would be, if I just do $stmt->execute(array("somevalue", b'somebinarydata', 10203, 201.3));, would the types be automatically recognized?

The answer is No, The PHP manual states:

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. **All values are treated as** *`PDO::PARAM_STR`.*

the page stating the entity `PDO::PARAM_STR` states:

> Represents the SQL CHAR, VARCHAR, or other string data type.

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the doc, if you want to specify type you do that beforehand, for example:

```
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

[**Example**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-954)

Comment: Is there any difference between `bindParam` and `bindValue`

Comment: @ultimatebuster -- read this and it explains the difference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: I know that, what I'm trying to ask is why is one better than another.

Comment: @ultimatebuster i do not know, you might have to ask another question or go through the doc for that